# Changing the locale of OK button in a MessageBox in InstallShield

Tags: installshield

We have a Basic MSI installer project. On a certain dialog, we do validations of data provided by user and then throw appropriate message using the MessageBox().

Now when the MessageBox comes up, it comes up with the message we want and an OK button.

We have an issue w.r.t the locale of this OK button. When tested on English, French windows 2008 machine we can get the OK button, where OK is in English. When we use the same installer on a Spanish windows machine then the same OK button comes up with OK in Spanish.

I'm not able to figure out what's the cause of this behaviour. Any hint/help would be of great help.

/Avadhut.

Answer (score 0):

It's unclear from your question exactly what API you call, and in exactly what scenario. Note that for almost everyone, displaying the OK button in the "native" language of the machine will not be confusing, so only causes problems during the QA process.

The `MessageBox` API of Windows is localized to the same locale as Windows itself. By contrast, [`MessageBoxEx` is documented](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms645507.aspx) to take a language parameter, although when I looked, a commenter said it doesn't always change the default localization. (My guess would be that the requested language was not available on the commenter's machine.)

If you're showing a message from within a MSI DLL custom action, it's better to use [`MsiProcessMessage`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa370354.aspx) than `MessageBox` as `MsiProcessMessage` will parent its window correctly. I suspect you're using a ControlEvent, which is implicitly avoided in a silent installation, but `MsiProcessMessage` will also not show its message during silent installations without requiring any extra work; if using `MessageBox` in an execute sequence action, you would have to check `UILevel` manually. However it's unclear from the documentation whether the buttons on an `MsiProcessMessage` message box will be localized.

Comment: I'm using MessageBox() API from InstallShield. Yes, i agree with you that displaying "OK" button in native language is the best, but my problem is that on all other supported locales (French/German) it's coming in English (i.e "OK"). So the question that still remains is why only on Spanish operating system it comes in Spanish.